# Java program exiting abnormally in Unix script

Tags: java, unix

I have inherited an extract job program which is a Java program that connects to a database and produces a file from a Unix shell script. At times, I can see the Java program is terminated abnormally and starts executing the remainder of the Unix script by zipping the extract. This is causing a lot of reconciliation issues.

The code is structured as follows:

```
INSTANCE_NAME=1
PROCESS_NAME=benefitpayment
cd utils
FAIL=0
sh benefitpaymentprocesswithdates.sh $PROCESS_NAME $INSTANCE_NUMBER $1 $2
for job in $dPidLst
do
wait $job || let "FAIL+=1"
done
echo $FAIL

if [ "$FAIL" == "0" ];
then
echo "About to secure file..."
zip -P <password> export.txt secure.zip
...
...
else
echo "FAIL! ($FAIL)"
fi
```

The $dPidLst is set in the inner Unix script(benefitpaymentprocesswithdates.sh) to call a Java wrapper and is set as:

```
java program called to generate a file
dPidLst=`jobs -p`
```

In either of the successful or failure cases, this "dPidLst" is always NULL.

The dPidLst is not exported in the inner script. The script was designed in that manner.

Should dPidLst be exported back to this main program? How do I make this script fool proof in the sense, if the Java program terminates abnormally, it should not execute the remainder of the Shell script? of zipping the file.

Comment: I think at successful completion you can write a success code on the console from java. Read that in the unix. If it is there then you are sure the code has completed successfully and you can execute the rest of the Unix script. Otherwise don't run the next steps. Or even you can write the success status in a text file and check for that file if its present then ok if its not then your program is exited abnormally.

Answer (score 0):

The value of dPidLst that you set in benefitpaymentprocesswithdates.sh will not be visible in your calling script.

When you run the benefitpaymentprocesswithdates script, it runs in its own process, and that process gets its own variables.

To pass the process id list back to your script, you need to use a mechanism other than shell variables or environment variables

e.g. at the end of benefitpaymentprocesswithdates.sh, do

```
echo $dPidList
```

And when you call it instead of

```
sh benefitpaymentprocesswithdates.sh
```

do

```
dPidList=$(sh benefitpaymentprocesswithdates.sh)
```

If all it is doing is calling `jobs -p`, there's no reason to have it in a separate script, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes in debug mode, I can see dPidList is set to a numeric value. Thanks let me check the 2nd approach